# How to calculate the stagnation temperature at the tip of the nose of a reentry module?

Tags: reentry, temperature

A re-entry module flies with Mach 10 at an ambient temperature of –27°C with. CP = 840 J/kg-K, gas constant R = 140 J/kg-K. What is the stagnation temperature at the tip of the nose of the re-entry module?

Comment: Homework problem?

Comment: @uhoh I don't believe that answer is relevant at all to this question. Before you edited it this was a simple gas thermodynamics 101 homework problem. Note that heating does not enter into it, and the 're-entry module' part is irrelevant, it could be any M 10 flow./

Comment: @OrganicMarble rolled-back. I had thought that homework problems were off-topic. I'm surprised to hear that heating does not enter into a question about temperature at the tip of a nosecone during reentry, so I'll wait for the answer to find out!

Comment: Check the mach number form of the equation here. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stagnation_temperature

Comment: Thank you, everyone, for your comments. The "Re-entry module" part is indeed irrelevant and I've realized that after going through the question properly. I basically got panicked as I don't have much idea about the reentry module.I have solved the question using the relation between Stagnation Temperature and Mach number.

Comment: @alamtania since you've solved your problem, consider posting an answer.  Answering your own question is fine on stack exchange!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: Solution]

Here's how I solved the question. Please ignore the (c) at the end of the solution.

Comment: Good work on this.  The caveat to this, of course, is that in a real-life application, the ideal gas assumptions used to derive these equations will break down at Mach numbers and temperatures that high.  The resulting temperature of a real gas with those thermodynamic properties at 300-ish K would be lower than this.