# Has there ever been an attempt or serious consideration for spacecraft to land on Mars without an ablative-type heat shield?

Tags: mars, landing, heat-shield, entry-descent-landing, ablator

[My answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/50118/12102) to *Do exploration spacecraft enter Mars atmosphere against Mars rotation, or on the same direction?* lauds the use of ablative heat shields for minimizing radiative heating of a spacecraft by the super-hot plasma sheath during atmospheric entry at Mars.

It then mentions that *I think that* the SpaceX Starship will use ceramic tiles for thermal shielding when landing on Mars rather than an ablative coating. I'm not 100% sure of that but it's not a premise of my question.

**Question:** Has there ever been an attempt or serious consideration for spacecraft to land on Mars without an ablative-type heat shield?

Comment: I would be surprised if any have--ablative shields are cheaper and just as good for a single use.

Comment: From https://nssdc.gsfc.nasa.gov/nmc/spacecraft/display.action?id=1971-045D it says for Soviet's Mars 2: Temperature control was maintained through thermal insulation and a system of radiators.  Can't seem to find more details to confirm if that means no ablation.

Comment: @eps cool, thanks! I've just asked [What were Mars 2's conical aerodynamic braking shield and “gunpowder” engines?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/50210/12102)

Comment: @eps I suspect that's talking about thermal management for the landed lander, not the reentry vehicle.

Comment: It's hard to answer "no" a "has there ever" type of question without infinite knowledge. Perhaps if you asked, "Is there a reentry speed beyond which, in practice, an ablative thermal protection system (TPS) is a better design choice than a non-ablative TPS?"

Comment: @phil1008 that's a great question, and it might have been asked, or there might be a related question to which an answer addresses it. In the mean time, I wonder if the most recent vision for SpaceX's Mars landing ship does or does not include an ablative aspect. Although we shouldn't make a habit of it, from time to time Stack Exchange questions do get asked to which an answer may not be forthcoming for several years or more. Let's see if your proposed question is really both unasked and unanswered currently.

Comment: @phil1008 in the mean time let's see if, three years later, there is an an answer to this question as-asked... I'll add a bounty to it.

Comment: @phil1008 Just fyi see NASA's [Low-Density Supersonic Decelerator (LDSD)](https://www.nasa.gov/tdm/low-density-supersonic-decelerator-ldsd-overview/) as discussed in [How did the tangential thrusters for the 2014 LDSD test spin-up then spin-down so nicely?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/19436/12102)

Answer (score 4):

All successful and attempted landings on Mars to date have used ablative heat shields. NASA shields have all been variants of phenolic impregnated carbon, sometimes with and oxide coating. The ESA missions have also used ablative heat shields although their composition is not publicly available. It's hard to find the details of Russian missions to Mars. Russian Soyuz Earth reentry capsules - the most widely used of all human flight vehicles - use an ablative glass-phenolic composite heat shield. It seems likely Russian Mars landing missions used the the same or similar materials.

The advantage of ablative heat shield is that it is cheap. The disadvantage is that it can be used only once.Non-ablative heat shields are desirable for spacecraft that are to be used more than once.The ceramic tiles on the Space Shuttle and Starship are examples.Carbon-carbon composites have been used on parts of the Space Shuttle that experienced less heating. Other refractory materials including metals are possible in principle, although they would not protect the cargo from heating and would likely require some spacing or insulating layer.

Non-ablative landing vehicles use entry descent and landing (EDL) techniques. A classic example was NASA's lunar landers, where the absence of an atmosphere on the Moon meant atmospheric breaking was impossible. For moon landings a spacecraft first used rocket propulsion to enter orbit. Subsequently a lander used propulsion to land on the Moon.

It's quite likely that (some) future Mars missions will use a similar approach, given the risk of direct atmospheric entry at high speed and the substantial deceleration involved, which would likely injure astronauts. A spacecraft will first use rockets to "brake" into Mars orbit and then a lander or the entire spacecraft will use EDL techniques to land on Mars. In these situations no heat shield is required, let alone an ablative one. In particular Robert Zubrin's Mars Direct mission proposals use this approach for EDL.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mars_Direct

In contrast, SpaceX appears to be designing a direct entry and landing mission involving aerobraking as well as retropropulsion. Such an approach would see a variant of Starship, likely with non-ablative reusable shields, land on Mars. The same vehicle will be required to return the astronauts to Earth, hence the heat shields must be reusable.

Comment: Source for the assertions in your first paragraph?

Comment: *Welcome to Stack Exchange!* Thanks for your answer. Just fyi see NASA's [Low-Density Supersonic Decelerator (LDSD)](https://www.nasa.gov/tdm/low-density-supersonic-decelerator-ldsd-overview/) as discussed in [How did the tangential thrusters for the 2014 LDSD test spin-up then spin-down so nicely?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/19436/12102)

Comment: ESA's most recent Mars lander, Schiaparelli, used Norcoat Liège which is a cork-based ablative material. (Liège is French for cork, as well as being the name of a city in Belgium.) You can find lots of information about it online.

Comment: @Organic Marble - multiple sources, e.g.
https://www.spiritaero.com/programs/defense/extreme-materials/pica/
https://web.archive.org/web/20110416170908/http://www.nasa.gov/offices/oce/appel/ask/issues/40/40s_space-x_prt.htm
The oxide coating - I can't remember now.

I was wrong about the ESA:
https://exploration.esa.int/web/mars/-/54509-heat-shields-for-the-schiaparelli-capsule
But it's ablative:
https://exploration.esa.int/web/mars/-/57828-a-stormy-arrival-for-schiaparelli

Comment: @Organic Marble
I couldn't find material on Russia's early Mars missions and AFAIK there have been no recent successful ones.
For Soyuz see page 2 here:
https://ntrs.nasa.gov/api/citations/20130013840/downloads/20130013840.pdf

Comment: I've not been able to find an example of a single-use atmospheric reentry vehicle that does not use an ablative heat shield. That includes ICBMs.

Comment: "Non-ablative landing vehicles use entry descent and landing (EDL) techniques", well, so do ablative landing vehicles. EDL encompasses all processes of entering the atmosphere and landing, whether that's heatshield/parachute or propulsive entry or something else entirely.

Comment: So to "Has there ever been an attempt **or serious consideration** for spacecraft to land on Mars without an ablative-type heat shield?" is your answer yes, or no?

Comment: @djr Indeed, Schiaparelli did. Unfortunately, if you remember, it also ended up leaving a big black smear on the face of Mars.

Comment: @uhoh As best I can determine for past missions, NO. I couldn't find any. I have not looked at all future proposed missions. No doubt many would imagine, non-ablative heat shields intended for Mars entry and return to Earth and reuse. Would you define these as "serious consideration" when they have not got past the concept stage? I haven't but YMMV.

Comment: OK, got it; *thanks!*